# Como Calcular atrasos en mysql

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

hola amigos estoy tratando de calcular los atrasos de los profesores... realizando la consulta me sale lo que quiero pero revisando los datos me sale en algunos campos con valores null.
Aqui la consulta:

```
SELECT th.codigopersonal, tp.nombres, tr.fecha, th.dia, th.j_codigo, 
th.hora_entrada, th.hora_salida, tr.hora_entra, 
tr.hora_sale,th.numero_horas, sec_to_time((time_to_sec (IF((tr.hora_entra > 
th.hora_entrada), (tr.hora_entra - th.hora_entrada),0))))as AtrEntrada, 
SEC_TO_TIME((time_to_sec(IF(tr.hora_sale < th.hora_salida, th.hora_salida-
tr.hora_sale,0))))as AtrSalida
from tb_horarios as th 
left JOIN tb_registroasistencia as tr ON th.codigopersonal=tr.psn_codigo AND 
th.dia= tr.dia AND th.j_codigo=tr.jnd_codigo
LEFT JOIN tb_personal_org as tp ON th.codigopersonal= tp.codigo
WHERE tr.fecha BETWEEN '2018-02-12' AND '2018-02-16'
GROUP BY th.codigopersonal, tr.fecha  
ORDER BY `tp`.`nombres` ASC
```

Aqui los resultados de la consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola Para esto tienes una funcion en MySQL llamada TIMEDIFF y DateDIFF te dejo un ejemplo:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2009-05-18 15:45:57.005678','2009-05-18 13:40:50.005670');
```

El resultado de esta consulta es:  02:05:07.000008

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(HORA_ENTRADA,HORA_FIJADA);
```

Espero te sirva Recuerdos!!

Comment: Gracias por contestar... me sirvió mucho tu respuesta

Comment: Excelente !! Saludos .. no olvides marar la respuestas como correcta :)

Comment: Hola amigo!! no se si me puede ayudar con algo... como en mi pregunta dice quiero calcular los atrasos en mysq  con el timediff me sale, pero me sale  en algunos resultados negativos no se si hay alguna manera en que me muestre si una persona llega tarde me muestre el atraso, pero si una persona marca antes de la hora de entrada me salga cero... no se si me puede ayudar!!!!...

Comment: puedes utilizar dos opciones 1-. hacer una condicional en tu aplicacion si es menor a 0 que ponga cero .. si no, pues el valor que te retonar el sql otra seria en el SQL on un if SELECT IF(-500<0, "0", "value");
SELECT IF(500<0, "0", "value");
 busca la manera de implementarlo me parece que hay alguna otra funcion que te podria ayudar mas si la encuentro te aviso

Comment: Gracias por contestar!!!... es la parte que me falta ya que es para la emisión de reportes...voy probar lo que me dices... gracias!!